Projecting $\mathbf{A}$ onto $\mathbf{X}_r = \mathbf{U}_r \mathbf{\Sigma}_r \mathbf{V}_r$ yields $\mathbf{U}_r^{*}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{U}_r$?
I am currently going through this Machine Learning paper ("Dynamic Mode Decomposition", page 8) and am stuck on quite a lot of things, but the one thing bugging me the most is the following: Let's assume that we have the SVD of $\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{U}\mathbf{\Sigma}\mathbf{V} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times N}$ and we consider it's rank-$r$ SVD truncation $\mathbf{X}_r = \mathbf{U}_r \mathbf{\Sigma}_r\mathbf{V}_r \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times N}$ gained by removing rows, rows and columns or columns of the matrices respectively. Now let's also consider $\mathbf{A}$ defined by the multiplication $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{Y}\mathbf{X}^{\dagger} = \mathbf{Y} \mathbf{V} \mathbf{\Sigma}^{\dagger}\mathbf{U}^{*} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ ($\mathbf{Y}$ is a matrix without any special properties). The authors claim that the projection of $\mathbf{A}$ onto the column space of $\mathbf{X}_r$ can be expressed as
$$\hat{\mathbf{A}} := \mathbf{U}_r^{*} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{U}_r$$
This looks... weird, since I don't see how (by the formula for the projection matrix)
$$\mathbf{X}_r(\mathbf{X}_r^{*}\mathbf{X}_r)^{-1}\mathbf{X}_r^{*} \mathbf{A} \stackrel{?}{=} \mathbf{U}^{*}_r \mathbf{A} \mathbf{U}_r$$
I've tried shuffling around terms that simplify to the identity in hopes to get it to the form on the right side, but I can't really see how any trick can lead to $\mathbf{U}_r$ ending up to the right of $\mathbf{A}$. Is this a typo, perhaps?

How can I arrive at the equality marked above with a question mark? Is it maybe just a typo?


The column space of $\mathbf X_r$ is the span of the columns of $\mathbf U_r$.
Computing $\mathbf U_r^* \mathbf A \mathbf U_r$ you're projecting support and range of $\mathbf A$ onto the span of the columns of $\mathbf U_r$ (and thus of $\mathbf X_r$).
This is perhaps easier to see using dyadic notation: $\mathbf U_r=\sum_k \mathbf u_k \mathbf e_k^*$, with $\mathbf u_k$ the $k$-th column of $\mathbf U_r$ and $\mathbf e_k$ the canonical orthonormal basis. Thus
$$\mathbf U_r^* \mathbf A \mathbf U_r
= \sum_{j,k} \mathbf e_k\mathbf e_j^* \langle \mathbf u_k, \mathbf X_r\mathbf u_j\rangle.$$
Although in fairness, I wouldn't strictly speaking call this a "projection", because you're also changing the space on which $\mathbf A$ acts. A "proper projection" would have been in this case perhaps better written as
$$(\mathbf U_r \mathbf U_r^*)\mathbf A(\mathbf U_r \mathbf U_r^*)
= \sum_{j,k} \mathbf u_k\mathbf u_j^* \langle \mathbf u_k, \mathbf X_r\mathbf u_j\rangle.$$
But practically speaking, as far as the data the paper probably cares about, the two objects are essentially equivalent.

I think you should change $\mathbf{X}_r$ to $\mathbf{A}$ to stay consistent with the question. I can follow why the column space (and thus the projection to it) of $\mathbf{U}_r$ and $\mathbf{X}_r$ is the same, but I still don't see how this is supposed to be a projection at all. Furthermore, what does "practically speaking [...] the two objects are essentially equivalent" mean in this context?

@TheOutZ you're right about $\mathbf A$, I edited. By "essentially the same" I mean that they are unitarily equivalent. So if what they're using these objects for doesn't care about the basis in which they are represented, it's fine to do things like they are
